# URL Query to filter WooCommerce products by ACF checkbox values?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I need to be able to filter WooCommerce products according to the values from an ACF field with a series of checkboxes e.g. Apples, Bananas, Grapes etc. Ideally I'd like to be able to do this with a URL query e.g. https://example.com/shop/?fruit=apples

I've been trying something along these lines with no success:

```
function product_initial_filter( $query ) {
if( !is_admin() ) {

    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'product' ) {

        if( isset($GET['fruit']) ) {
            $query->set('meta_value', $GET['fruit']);
            $query->set('meta_key', 'fruits');
            $query->set('meta_compare', 'IN');
        }

    }
}

// return
return $query;

}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'product_initial_filter');
```

Comment: why are you returning `return $query;`?

Comment: What didn't work? What do you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass meta argument in `meta_query`. and also if you are `'compare' => 'IN',` the value must be an array.  check the below code.

> Using WP `pre_get_posts` action hook.

```
function product_initial_filter( $query ) {

    if( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() ) {

        if( $query->get('post_type') == 'product' && isset( $GET['fruit'] ) && $GET['fruit'] != '' ) {

            $meta_query = array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'fruits',
                    'value'   => array( $GET['fruit'] ),
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                ),
            );
            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

        }

    }

}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'product_initial_filter');
```

**OR**

> Using WC `woocommerce_product_query` action hook.

```
function product_initial_filter( $query ) {

    if( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() ) {

        if( $query->get('post_type') == 'product' && isset( $GET['fruit'] ) && $GET['fruit'] != '' ) {

            $meta_query = array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'fruits',
                    'value'   => array( $GET['fruit'] ),
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                ),
            );
            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

        }

    }

}
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'product_initial_filter');
```

USEFUL LINKS.

- [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/)
- [woocommerce_product_query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/includes/class-wc-query.php#L493)
- [meta_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters)

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried them both but it still doesn't seem to be doing anything unfortunately. It's the WooCommerce shop page but built with Elementor (using the archive products widget) if that makes any difference to the query.

Comment: Btw, just in case anyone else copies your code, where you've got your `add_action`s, `product_filter` should read `product_initial_filter`.

Comment: You should also change your question.